# Can I control what gets copied into CPU cache in C++?

Tags: c++, memory-management, cpu-cache

I read about cache optimization in C++ and the mechanisms, modern CPUs use to predict what data is needed next, to copy that into cache. But is there a direct way in C++ for the programmers, who know what actually is needed next, to determine what data gets copied into CPU cache?

Comment: What you _access_ will get copied into the cache. Now, aligment will do a bit, valgrind cachegrind to do the rest. (And no, there is no direct control. Even if there was, no sane OS would expose that :))

Comment: @sehe There are processors with explicit control; AltiVec comes to mind. You define an input stream which acts as a strong, sticky hint to the prefetcher. But if OP doesn't have the presence of mind to mention *what* he's programming, it's probably better not to get into this at all.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This varies with the processor and compiler you're using.

Assuming you're using an Intel x86/x64 or compatible (e.g., AMD) processor, the processor provides a number of prefetch instructions, and most compilers include intrinsics to invoke them. With VC++ you use `_m_prefetch` or `_m_prefetchw`. With gcc you use `__builtin_prefetch`.

Likewise, VC++ on an ARM provides a `__prefetch` intrinsic for the same purpose (no, I really don't know why they couldn't have used the same name as on x86; the signature and effect appear identical).

Most other reasonably modern, higher-end processors probably provide similar instructions, and 
I'd guess most compilers provide intrinsics to make them available, *but* just as with these, the names of the intrinsics will vary. For that matter, even though the functions are intrinsic to the compiler, most require that you include some header to use them -- and the name of the header will also vary.

Answer (score 2):

The prefetch intrinsics Jerry provided would do the trick. keep in mind that there are several flavors controlled by an argument to that function, determining which levels of the cache (if any) would be used to keep the line. A prefetch_NTA for e.g. would not pollute the caches, but rather provide the line only for immediate use (and is used in cases where you're going to use it soon and once only)

Also keep in mind that these instructions are basically hints to the CPU (which also does quite well by itself trying to guess which lines to prefetch). As such, they are *not* guaranteed to work, they might fail in many cases (if the memory subsystem is loaded, or the address got swapped out of memory).